# Semi-norm on essentially bounded functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space of essentially bounded functions (before quotienting it to create the $L^\infty$ space).
On that space, I read, $|||.|||_\infty$ is only a semi-norm.
So I wanted to find an example, i.e. a function $f$ which is $0$ a.e. (but not identically $0$) such that $f$ has no point $y\neq 0$ in its essential range with:
$$\mu (f^{-1}(U))>0 $$
where $U$ is any neighborhood of $y$ and $\mu$ the relevant measure.

I can't find an example with obvious functions. Anyone knows one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any function that is zero almost everywhere but not identically zero will do. Let $f$ be such a function, and assume for simplicity that $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x$. Then $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ has measure zero if and only if $a>0$, so
$$\text{ess}\sup_x f(x):=\inf\{a\in\mathbb{R}\,:\,\mu(f^{-1}(a,\infty))=0\}=\inf(0,\infty)=0.$$
Hence $\|f\|_\infty=\text{ess}\sup_x|f(x)|=\text{ess}\sup_x f(x)=0$. But $f\neq0$.